# Counting Process Repetitions in SQL using Partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2017

FYI - I really wasn't sure what title to give this question.  Any guidance is most welcome.

Below I have a "parent" rug (A12345) that is eventually cut into 2 or more rugs.  These rugs need to go through rigorous washing and I need to know how many washings that rug went through between the "Parent" and "Child" rugs.

So in total, "A12345-678" had 4 washings before it was cut, and then 3 washings after when it became separate.

Using the sequence number, I have to be able to label the process as the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc...  With the Process_Num column being the desired column I'm trying to achieve in SQL.

```
Rug_Num Sequence_Num    Process Process_Num
A12345  10              Wash    1st Wash
A12345  11              Wash    2nd Wash
A12345  30              Wash    4th Wash
A12345  20              Wash    3rd Wash

 '----Rug cut into 2 child rugs'

A12345-678  40          Wash    5th Wash
A12345-678  50          Wash    6th Wash
A12345-678  60          Wash    7th Wash

A12345-997  40          Wash    5th Wash
A12345-997  50          Wash    6th Wash
A12345-997  60          Wash    7th Wash
A12345-997  70          Wash    8th Wash
```

Here is my "in-progress" statement but I can't figure out how to add something after "THEN" that will cause it to sequentially number the current sequence as "1st, 2nd, 3rd".  My mind says to put another `COUNT CASE WHEN` after the 1st `THEN` but it will then be an infinite statement.

```
WITH toupdate AS (
    SELECT m.*,
        count(CASE WHEN (m.Process = 'Wash' 
                        AND m.Rug_Num = m.Rug_Num
                        AND m.sequence_num < m.sequence_num)
                        THEN  1 ELSE 0 END)
         OVER (PARTITION BY m.Process, m.Rug_Num, m.Process_Num) AS Process_Num_New
         FROM mfng_data m
        )
    UPDATE toupdate
        SET Process_Num = ISNULL(Process_Num_New,0);
```

So above I was trying to replicate a `COUNTIFS` (Excel) in SQL.  The Excel example is below.  The formula in Column H is:

```
=(COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$14,C3,$D$3:$D$14,"<"&D3,$E$3:$E$14,"Wash")+1)+IF(LEN(C3)>6,COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$14,$C$3,$E$3:$E$14,"Wash"),0)
```

I add the +1 so it will count how many were less than the current sequence and add 1 for the current sequence.

[image: Excel_Example]

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.1000.169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `count(*)` with window function `over()`

there are 2 `count()` in the query below. The first one count the wash no for parent, and the 2nd `count()` is on the child

```
select  *, 
        Wash_No = count (case when Parent_Rug = Rug_Num then 1 end) 
                   over (partition by Parent_Rug order by Sequence_num) 
                + count (case when Parent_Rug <> Rug_Num then 1 end)  
                   over (partition by Rug_Num order by Sequence_num)

from    mfng_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following way

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
Rug_Num varchar(10),
Sequence_Num int,
Process varchar(10),
Process_Num int
)

INSERT TestTable(Rug_Num,Sequence_Num,Process)VALUES
 ('A12345',    10,'Wash')
,('A12345',    11,'Wash')
,('A12345',    30,'Wash')
,('A12345',    20,'Wash')
,('A12345-678',40,'Wash')
,('A12345-678',50,'Wash')
,('A12345-678',60,'Wash')
,('A12345-997',40,'Wash')
,('A12345-997',50,'Wash')
,('A12345-997',60,'Wash')
,('A12345-997',70,'Wash')


;WITH numCTE AS(
  SELECT Sequence_Num,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Sequence_Num) Process_Num
  FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT Sequence_Num
      FROM TestTable
    ) q
)
UPDATE t
SET
  t.Process_Num=n.Process_Num
FROM TestTable t
JOIN numCTE n ON t.Sequence_Num=n.Sequence_Num


SELECT *
FROM TestTable
```